# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a question application. I am trying to create a list in order to put icons in it so that if the person answers the question, the result of the answer will appear, but I saw this error inside the row!!!
**The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.dartargument_type_not_assignable **

-> this is the code

```
class exampage extends StatefulWidget {
  const exampage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<exampage> createState() => _exampageState();
}

class _exampageState extends State<exampage> {
  List answerResult = [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.check,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 135, 76),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.close,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 223, 84, 75),
      ),
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
      Row(
        children: answerResult,
      ),
```

Isn't everything correct, what's the problem with the error?

what should I try ?

Comment: Row aspects List<Widget> in children arg and answerResult is of type List<dynamic> becouse you didn't specified default type is dynamic type for List, you can fix this by providing Widget type to List like, List<Widget> answerResult.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution if you have the same error just add `<Widget>` after list

like this :

```
List<Widget> answerResult = [
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  child: Icon(
    Icons.check,
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 135, 76),
  ),
),
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  child: Icon(
    Icons.close,
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 223, 84, 75),
  ),
),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Explaining @Balkis's Answer:
To resolve this issue, specify the type of the List when you declare answerResult. If you do not specify the type of a List in dart it is considered as dynamic type. So change:

```
List answerResult = [
```

to:

```
List<Widget> answerResult = [
```

With this change, you're explicitly telling Dart that answerResult is a List of Widgets, and you shouldn't encounter the error when you use it in the Row's children.